# Dart: What is the difference between .toList() and casting as List

Tags: list, dart, casting

Out of curiosity and after some research I did not find the same case as mine,

What is the difference between using the method `.toList()` and casting `as List` and when should each be used?

Kindly, consider providing an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toList()` is a method called on multiple types of objects and will gather all data from a data stream (or existing `List`) and create a new List object containing the data.

`as List` is a way to tell a given object (often `dynamic`) is in fact a `List` object on runtime. This is used if we cannot determined the type on compile type (e.g. if parsing JSON).

**Example**

We decodes some JSON and tell Dart that we can guarantee that the type on runtime will be `List` by using `as List`.

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final list = json.decode('[1, 2, 3]') as List;
  print(list); // [1, 2, 3]

  final newList = list.cast<int>().map((e) => e * 2).toList();
  print(newList); // [2, 4, 6]
}
```

We then use `.map` to double each value and want to convert this into a new list by usin `toList()`.